# Как автоматически открыть shell, чтобы туда автоматически вводились команды bash используя питон?

Tags: python

я хочу сделать скрипт для автоматизации 15 строк bash на питоне. Хочу чтобы у меня открывалась оболочка shell и в ней вводились автоматически команды bash, например:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", shell =True, 
                           stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
                           stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate("sudo -i")
process.communicate("123")
```

Что-то типа такого, но это не работает. Оболочка открывается, но никакие команды не выполняются и ничего не выводится если сделать print('..'). 
Только не предлагайте переделать эту задачу с помощью shellpy, или запускать скриптовый файл sh.
Я хочу именно сделать так чтобы у меня открывалась консоль и в ней начали происходить всякие действия.

Как так сказать, переключиться на созданное окно?

Comment: А почему бы не вызвать `/bin/sh`? Терминал Gnome работает не совсем так, как Вы думаете :)

Comment: PyAutoGUI тоже не предлагать ?

Answer (score 0):

pyAutoGui, а что так можно было?:) Да, теперь у меня вписываются команды в запускаемый терминал, правдо кое-что странно:(https://ibb.co/wh5fB2j)
с таким кодом:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", shell =True)
process1.wait()
pyautogui.PAUSE =100000
pyautogui.write('sudo -i')
```

а если уменьшить паузу , то sudo -i запишется в поисковое окно, но думаю тему можно считать закрытой.

P.S. /bin/sh не подходит так как запускается только внутри терминала, а я бы хотел отдельное окно.